# Recyclerview Scrolling Glitch

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I had some problem about scrolling with Card inside RecyclerView. There some additional gaps when I scroll inside the RecyclerView, you can see it in this gif:

[image]

This is my adapter. Is this because the fragment or what ?

```
public class PosItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PosItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> itemList;
    private ArrayList<CartItem> cartList;
    private Boolean isMixed = false;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public ImageView picture;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView desc;
        public TextView price;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            picture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_pos_item_picture);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_pos_item_name);
            price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_pos_item_price);

        }
    }

    public PosItemAdapter(ArrayList<Item> itemList, Boolean isMixed) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.isMixed = isMixed;
    }

    public Item getValueAt(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_pos_item_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (itemList != null) {
            return itemList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: provide some code

Comment: Since I can't tell if you've implemented the `RecyclerView` correctly, I'll point you to this [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), take a look at the Tips and Tricks at the bottom.  You can also try to disable hardware acceleration on the view and see if the behavior changes.  Do all devices show the same artifact?

Comment: I had a similar issue when i was using few animations for the items. Have you tried remove the animations?

Comment: @RahulKhurana updated with my adapter

Comment: @GaryBak Let me try disable my hardware acceleration. Yes it happens on other devices too

Comment: you are not setting anything in the onBindViewHolder method

Comment: i recommend to get context from constructor and in onCreateViewHolder method use that context object while inflating layout

Comment: @GaryBak I disabled the hardware acceleration and the problem still exists

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes I remove the code

Comment: i am afraid without the code we are not able you to suggest any new way.

Comment: @RahulKhurana you can see the full code here http://pastebin.com/GHcJNzNT

Comment: @Souto I don't think I'm using any animations

Comment: Try removing the dynamic loading of the images from external storage and just use the static resource code path `holder.picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);` see if that helps the refresh.  It's not a solution, just trying to identify the issue.

Comment: @GaryBak already remove external image, but the glitch still exist

Comment: Post your layout code.  Initially I thought a row was missing and it was drawn late, but it is actually the row scrolled off jumping back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was my card height. I set to wrap_content and the glitch fixed.

Comment: Be careful with cardsize set to wrap_content. If your card content changes, even if the dimensions do not end up different, it can cause the recyclerview to scroll unexpectedly. Try to set the card height programmatically during the bind.